# Webkit Overflow Scrolling Snap to elements

Tags: css, webkit, mobile-safari

Using the new -webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch technique, is it possible to get it to snap to elements to.

EG:: this to snap to the images

```
.gallery {
    width:960px;
    height:600px;
    overflow:auto;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch;
}
img {
    width:800px;
    height:600px;
    float:left;
}

<div class="gallery">
    <img src="101.jpg"/>
    <img src="101.jpg"/>
    <img src="101.jpg"/>
    <img src="101.jpg"/>
    <img src="101.jpg"/>
    <img src="101.jpg"/>
    <img src="101.jpg"/>
    <img src="101.jpg"/>
    <img src="101.jpg"/>
    <img src="101.jpg"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;` just tells iOS and other mobile browsers (not sure if there are any more mobile Webkit-based browsers) that the list is scrollable via touch. It doesn't define behavior.

You'll need to implement a solution in JS.

Comment: I've recently used https://github.com/BoostCommunications/Flickable for horizontal snapping. Works like a charm and is rather simple.